# Problems with AuthenticateAsync with Facebook login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I have a problem enabling Facebook auth in my ASP.NET Core web app. I'm using ASP.NET Core Authentication but *not* Identity. The auth is configured in Startup like this:

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "clientid";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signinfacebookcallback";
    });
```

As shown in the code, I want to use cookie auth, but also allow people to sign in with Facebook. Once they have been successfully signed in, I want to set the auth cookie.

To show the challenge, I have the following action:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("signinfacebook")]
public ActionResult SignInFacebook()
{
    return Challenge(FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

This redirects the user to the Facebook login screen. Once they sign in, the user is redirected to the URL specified in config:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("signinfacebookcallback")]
public async Task<ActionResult> SignInFacebookCallback()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
    if (!result.Succeeded) return Redirect("/login/");

    ...
}
```

When I debug the code, `result.Succeeded` returns false and the `AuthenticationResult` object doesn't contain more information on why `Succeeded` is false.

I verified that the app id and secret are correct.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Hmm, usually you don't implement the callback path handler.. It should get handled by the Facebook authentication handler's RemoteAuthenticate.

Comment: Is that because you are using Identity? Or do you have an example of how to implement that without Identity?

Comment: Nope, no Identity used. At least the OpenID Connect authentication handler handles callbacks by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CallbackPath`  in the OpenID Connect middleware is internal path that are used for the authentication flow of the OpenID Connect protocol. After Identity provider redirect user to that url in your application , middeware will handle token valiation ,token decode,exchange token and finally fill the user principle , and that process is fired before your controller gets involved .

Since `CallbackPath` is internal and will handled by OpenID Connect middleware automatically , you don't need to care about , make sure the callback is registered in facebook's allowed redirect url and let middleware handle the callback .If you want to redirect user to specific route/page after authentication , put the url to `AuthenticationProperties` :

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/home/Privacy" } ,FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

And you should remove the callback path route (`signinfacebookcallback`) in your application .

**UPDATE**

If you want to access database and manage local user , you can use built-in events in middleware, for `AddFacebook` middleware , you can use `OnTicketReceived` to add access database , manage users and add claims to user's princple  :

```
.AddFacebook(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    options.CallbackPath = "/signinfacebookcallback";
    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
        {

            //query the database to get the role
            var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
            // add claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I think you are right in the fact that the middleware handles the callback from Facebook. In my case, I want a callback, though. It's fine that the middleware sign in the user. But in the case this is the first sign in from Facebook, I want a hook to create the user in my local database. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I also would like great control of what the callback puts inside `User.Identity.Name`. Currently, it simply put the full name from Facebook. I would rather use an identifier there.

Comment: That looks exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: And then maybe not. After calling the `AddIdentity` method in `OnTicketReceived`, `User.Identity.Name` is still the Facebook full name when accessed from a controller. This is the code that tries to set that value: `claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id));`

Comment: @ThomasArdal , you don't need to add claims in event . Facebook will provide userid , you can directly get that in controller `var userid = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;`

Comment: Yep. But I want `User.Identity.Name` to always contain the id of the currently logged in user. For cookie auth (username/password) I set this in my login action to do this: `claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id));`. So wanted the Facebook even handler to "mimic" this. But it doesn't look like I can overwrite claims set by the Facebook middleware.

Comment: @ThomasArdal try below codes in `OnTicketReceived ` :`var identity = ctx.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                var claimsRemove = identity.Claims
                    .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).FirstOrDefault();

                identity.RemoveClaim(claimsRemove);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "userid"));
                return Task.CompletedTask;`

Comment: That works, thanks! There might be a way to set this through claim mapping. But I'll look into that. Thanks again.